# LARAVEL serve on a ip but let laravel think its on a domain

Tags: php, laravel, proxy, proxypass, serve

I'm running laravel serve on a local ip, and using a local ProxyPass server to reverse a public domain to that local ip.

The only problem is that when im using `{{asset('...')}}` laravel is placing the ip in front of the location of that asset. This will result in a 404 for that requested file.

Example:
`php artisan serve --host=192.168.178.2 --port=1234`

My ProxyPass server passes all requests from `example.com` tot that local server.

This works, but on the places where I have used `{{asset('...')}}` in my code there is not `'example.com/css/app.css'` but is `'192.168.178.2/css/app.css'`

Is there a way to serve on a IP, but laravel thinks its on a domain?

Comment: Does anything here help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912997/laravel-routes-behind-reverse-proxy

Comment: Also try setting `ProxyPreserveHost On` in your Apache config file. That might be easier than anything else there.

Comment: Thanks for the link, sadly that code is for 5.5, i'm on 5.7 and there is no routes.php file there. But I think that may be the solution, just not to my version. I dont want my proxy server to change content that it is pushing trough. Laravel needs to do that. And I don't think ProxyPreserveHost On will work. Because larvel is setting that ip in the code, not my proxy or php artisan serve.

Comment: I need this for Laravel 5.7: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29913894/7257689) but I don't have the ```routes.php``` file

Comment: `ProxyPreserveHost On` is precisely to retain the requested hostname when proxying. It does not change the content. Give that a try and get back to me.

Comment: Also, the routes files for 5.7 are stored in the `routes` subdirectory. You want `routes/web.php`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, thanks to [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811240/mike)!
Because of the old [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912997/laravel-routes-behind-reverse-proxy) he advised me to visit. I found some new search terms for google. And then I found a [GitHub post](https://gist.github.com/tadeubarbosa/34aa8a87f4d56e9e1480846f3e20f41d) that just works with the latest Laravel 5.7.

Add the following code to `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    /** @var \Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator $url */
    $url = $this->app['url'];
    // Force the application URL
    $url->forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));
}
```

Comment: You should add the relevant code here. Link-only answers are frowned upon.