# Laravel 5.5 APP_URL not changing

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to change the path output of `{{ url('images/image.png') }}` and `{{ asset('images/image.png') }}`  Based on my reading, it sounds like I just need to set APP_URL in my .env file and off we go.  Well, unfortunately that is not the case.  I have set `APP_URL=http://localhost` in my .env file.  I also set `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://broken.af')` in my config/app.php file. Additionally, I have also tried setting ASSET_URL in both locations with the same result.  I have also run `artisan cache:clear`, `artisan config:clear` and `artisan config:cache`.  I also tried restarting the server just to be extra sure.  For some reason Laravel keeps using the servers configured hostname for these values.

Not a dupe, we are not talking about the route paths, we are talking about the url and asset function and APP_URL and ASSET_URL not doing anything.

Comment: what you should be looking for is `ASSET_URL` not `APP_URL`

Comment: Where is ASSET_URL documented...

Comment: You should be able to set it in your `env` file and also in `config/app.php`

Comment: The only doc I can find on it is under https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers documentation.  It doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Ok. I use 5.8. If you have all your assets in the public folder you shouldn't have problems with assets except you move them to some other location

Comment: I am having an issue because I need to host it behind a reverse proxy, I have no idea why this is such a PITA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197370/discussion-between-udo-e-and-alex-barker).

Comment: Value in your `.env` file and `config/app.php` must be same. From your question, they aren't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel routes behind reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912997/laravel-routes-behind-reverse-proxy)

Comment: I definitely don't want to set the routing path, that works fine.This is not a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go ahead and post the answer to my question.  If `UrlGenerator::forceRootUrl` is not used, it will inevitably fallback to `Request::root()` which is implemented as follows: `return rtrim($this->getSchemeAndHttpHost().$this->getBaseUrl(), '/');`

I am not sure what ASSET_URL or SITE_URL do, if anything.  These env variables are definitely not used in the `url` or `asset` functions.  This does not appear to have changed in later versions of Laravel.

The only way I was able to find to get these variables to work was to manually read them in `RouteServiceProvider::boot()` and then call forceRootUrl.

```
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        /** @var UrlGenerator $url */
        $url = $this->app['url'];

        // Force the application URL
        $url->forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));
    }
```

The trace:

1. https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/UrlGenerator.php#L204
2. https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/UrlGenerator.php#L492
3. https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/UrlGenerator.php#L494
4. https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/Request.php#L89

Comment: Thank you save my weekend. I believe this step is needed in case of a badly configured Laravel application when going in production: the developer forgot something to enable the APP_URL (I'm not a Laravel expert as you can see).

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to get an asset, in your case it's an image it will be right to use `asset()`  laravel helper,

for more information, please check [laravel method-asset helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset)

Comment: So both asset and url return the same thing outlined above.

Comment: nop, asset can be another url maybe s3 or any storage

Comment: I know they "can be," I am saying that even with APP_URL and ASSET_URL configured in both the .env and config/app.php has the same result as outlined in my post... I am really at a loss here.

Comment: your images folder is under the public folder ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have all your assets in the default public folder, use the Fully Qualified Domain Name (including **security protocol**) for your `APP_URL` in your `.env` file. Example:

```
APP_URL=https://broken.af
```

Also use the same for your `config/app.php` file:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://broken.af'),
```

Comment: If it wasn't clear from my initial post, its not using these values despite them being set.

Answer (score 0):

If this is helpful for someone, this code worked for me:

```
$url = env('APP_URL').Storage::url($file->path);
```

This is how I'm saving the file previously:

```
$file->path = $request->file("file")->store("public");
```

I found this answer [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-env)

p.d. Don't forget to do the symlink like documentation mention [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

```
php artisan storage:link
```